# Google suddenly started to return validation as false using LightOpenId

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

Using LightOpenID library, I managed to successfully implement OpenID in my website. 
However, a few days ago, it simply stopped to work when using Google as provider (it runs fine using Yahoo!).
Since the day I implemented OpenID, it runned fine using any provider. I even had a few users using their Google Accounts to login. However, strangely, a few days ago Google stopped to work (while other providers still run fine), returning false on $openid->validate()

I tested using the example-google.php file with no modifications, provided by LightOpenID, but I had no luck. I also tested using different Google Accounts, no luck too. I even tested on different websites, but still no luck. Note that I am using shared host and curl is installed, running version 7.19.7

Did Google make any recent changes on it's system that is now causing this? Is there any other reason for this problem?

Comment: Was this issue solved? how was it done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other people are saying to enable cURL (which may be your issue), but in my case cURL was enabled.

Some more snooping around and I found out that the request was going through request_streams() due to the following check failing in the function **request** (formatted for convenience):

```
if (
  function_exists( 'curl_init' ) &&
  (
    !in_array( 'https', stream_get_wrappers() ) ||
    !ini_get( 'safe_mode' ) &&
    !ini_get('open_basedir' )
  )
) {
```

Change it to:

```
if (
  function_exists( 'curl_init' ) &&
  (
    !in_array( 'https', stream_get_wrappers() ) ||
    (
      !ini_get( 'safe_mode' ) &&
      !ini_get( 'open_basedir' )
    )
  )
) {
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: Forgot to say that I'm unsure if Google did make some change, but the fact that a lot of people using the same library having the same problem at the same time means something happened, and I can say that most people probably didn't change a thing. Google probably flicked some switch to make something more restrictive/secure.

Comment: Thank you for your response! But, unfortunately, didn't work for me. I do have cURL enabled (curl_init() works with no problem), making this problem even more frustrating. I tried to remove this check and automatically use request_curl(), but didn't worked too.

Comment: That is strange. This worked for me, so I thought that it might have worked for you. Sorry I couldn't help more. The strangest part about this was that it was working for everyone until a few days back. Google what have you done ? -- Ninja Edit: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694986/google-openid-not-working-with-openid-plugin-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit more info to this thread.

I had issue with the file stream (on 'file_get_contents') also. I forced curl as described above.
(Issue with Google only. Yahoo was working fine)

With my shared hosting, I also had to comment out the 'CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION' option.