# Bolt Extension Repo Currently Unavailable

Tags: php, xampp, bolt-cms

I am running Bolt CMS locally on my machine using XAMPP. I just upgraded to version 2.0.1 today and everything seems to be working great. The only issue I am having is installing extensions.

On the view/install extensions page, I am seeing this message:

> The Bolt extensions Repo at https://extensions.bolt.cm/list.json is currently unavailable. Check your connection and try again shortly.

I do have an active internet connection and am not sure why I cannot connect to the repository from the extensions page. Any help would be appreciated!

### Update

In the CommandRunner.php file's setup method, there is this line:

> $json = json_decode((file_get_contents($this->packageRepo)));

The problem is coming from the file_get_contents($this->packageRepo) call

The error message being returned from that call is

> file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

### Update 2

The issue is not related to bolt CMS but rather my XAMPP configuration. However, if someone else using bolt CMS locally with XAMPP has already tackled this issue, I would appreciate their input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, I have not been able to solve the SSL issue with my local server.

I did, however, find a solution that allows me to install bolt extensions.

The solution is to open up the config.yml file and add the following:

> extensions: 
>     site: 'http://extensions.bolt.cm/'

This will tell bolt to use the http URL rather than https. I would recommend using the secure URL in production, but this has allowed me to install extensions on my local server until I solve the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following fixed it correctly for me!

[PHP cURL error code 60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114371/php-curl-error-code-60)

From that post:

> Use this certificate root certificate bundle:
>
> https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
>
> Copy this certificate bundle on your disk. And use this on php.ini
>
> ```
> curl.cainfo = "path_to_cert\cacert.pem"
> ```