# Oauth2 Vs meetup using php and curl, fails to get token

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, meetup

respect to the whole stack exchange community,

Tried to hold off for as long as i can(7 days) before asking, who/what is responsible for the following errors:

```
{"error":"invalid_client"}
```

According to the documentation:
http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/auth/#oauth

```
invalid_client  = Client authentication failed
```

which doesn't help me know as much as i would like.

Basically i am dealing with Oauth 2, meetup api, php and curl. The latter 2 i am reasonably comfortable with.

So who is at fault here?

I can see that the code comes back

```
oauth-meetup.php?code=e7f7523c66776c41e001acd00dc48e2a&state=
```

as a response i just can't get a valid token.

i had a feeling it might be a SSL/cert issue so i followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114371/php-curl-error-code-60)
but got this error:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid code"}
```

then i set

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0
```

no difference.

The issue must surely be isolated to my setup, however i really need help, i [want to attach the code here](http://webdesignfavourites.com/B613/oauth-login-public.zip) if you can please help me!

Comment: there's no SSL/cert issue: since you get an OAuth error response from the server it means that it has connected succesfully; please show the code that you use to exchange the `code` for an `access_token` as the error must be in there

Comment: I forgot to mention support sent me this " It looks like you are using the same authorization code more than once.

You can only use the authorization code you get back from our servers after obtaining member authorization once in this oauth step -- http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/auth/#oauth2server-access "   But the script checks if the code is empty so i dont see how this is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in the link: can you verify that you use the correct `client_id` and `client_secret` and that they don't contain "special" characters, such as `&`? Since the code in `socialmedia_oauth_connect.php` does not properly URL-encode the `client_id` and `client_secret` that is a problem when their values contain characters that are not URL-safe.

Comment: client_id=r70fm0aITSOKbr0hj0eis5tuh&client_secret=2k54knITSOK88rm2kdq3u63ggr&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.webdesignfavourites.com%2Fwp%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fwp-hq-membership%2Fclasses%2Foauth-login%2Fhq-oauth-meetup.php%3F&code=e313791a57111e178d3ddd622a805849

Comment: So yeah i changed the client id & secret slightly for security, but they look well formed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was encoding.

Use either http_build_query:

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
```

or

```
        ."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($this->redirect_uri)
```