# Laravel 5.2 reset password + Mandrill

Tags: laravel, mandrill, laravel-5

I have Laravel 5.2 fresh installation.

I did following:

1. I have set up my `.env` file 
   `MAIL_DRIVER=mandrill
   SECRET=my_mandrill_api_key`
2. I have installed Guzzle (https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)
3. I have setup my email in view (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/resources/views/emails/password.blade.php)
4. I have fixed the certificate issue ([PHP cURL error code 60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114371/php-curl-error-code-60))

So it seems everything is done correctly.

When I fill email to reset password and press Send Password Reset Link button, I get following error

> Server error: `POST
>   https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-raw.json` resulted in a
>   `500 Internal Server Error` response:
>   {"status":"error","code":-1,"name":"ValidationError","message":"You
>   must specify a key value"}

I have check my log in Mandrill (https://mandrillapp.com/settings/api) there is no logs for my action.

From the error of Mandrill, I know it does not get the api key, so for some reason the api key and other values is not passing over to Mandrill api.

**Question:** What is missing/wrong?

Note: right now I am working on my local environment building the app. My local environment Windows 10/Bitnami WAMP stack 7/ I am also using Mandrill API.

[image]

Comment: message":"You must specify a key value,  could you add the code of the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Mandrill driver then you must set the `MANDRILL_SECRET` in your .env file.

The other settings `MAIL_HOST`, `MAIL_PORT` and so on are for use with other drivers.

See the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#introduction) about using the Mandrill driver. It mentions that you should set the Mandrill key in `config/services.php` but you should really set that using an environment variable, so if you have customized the file change it back to

```
'mandrill' => [
    'secret' => env('MANDRILL_SECRET'),
],
```

Then you will be able to read the `MANDRILL_SECRET` value from the .env file.

So in your .env file you'll have;

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mandrill
MANDRILL_SECRET=your_mandrill_key_here
```

Comment: I am setting it up from .env file not from services,

Comment: Yep I suggested making the change there, just make sure that your config/services.php looks like that for the mandrill group.

Comment: Thanks so far for the answer