# Validation error in mandrill in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, mandrill

I have tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453908/laravel-5-2-reset-password-mandrill) but I had no luck.

**.env file:**

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=****
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
MAIL_DRIVER=mandrill
MANDRILL_SECRET=**********
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mandrillapp.com
MAIL_USERNAME=user_name
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****    
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_PORT=465
```

**mail.php**

```
return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mandrill'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mandrillapp.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
    'from' => ['address' => 'rnytt1@mediadigital.no', 'name' => 'Digital Magazine'],
   'encryption'=> env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

];
```

**services.php**

```
  'mandrill' => [
    'secret' => env('secret_key')//zGvUgEUh9E6L2dyN7x7NDg
],
```

**Error:**

I could have a look at my [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGsgl.png)

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might miss to set your API key up config/services.php and you will see this

```
'mandrill' => [
    'secret' => env('MANDRILL_SECRET'),
],
```

Set an ENV var for MANDRILL_SECRET so it uses that for the API requests