# Opencart-instamojo: Curl error message: SSL certificate issue: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: php, ssl, curl, opencart2.x, instamojo

I am using **instamojo** as payment gateway in my **opencart**.

**Opencart version is:2.0.3.1**

I download **instamojo** from https://github.com/Instamojo/Instamojo-OpenCart-2.0 and follow the instruction as stated here.

After success full implementation I pay using **instamojo**. But after payment I redirect to the cart page instead of success page. No order is get in admin panel nor email is received.

I check the error log located in  `system/logs/imojo.log`

It shows:

```
2016-04-04 14:35:13 - Curl error no: 60 || Curl error message: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
2016-04-04 14:35:13 - Payment for this ID(xxxxxxx) was not successful: null
2016-04-04 14:35:13 - Response from server is null.
2016-04-04 14:35:13 - Payment for xxxxxxx was not credited.
```

I follow the link  http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/  to create CA certificate and put the file in `C:/wamp/www/MyCACertificate.crt`

And add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/MyCACertificate.crt");
```

in `_getcurlInfo` function
in    `catalog/controller/payment/instamojo.php`

And change **php.ini** file as `curl.cainfo = "c:/wamp/www/MyCACertificate.crt"`

But showing same error in log **Curl error message: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain**

How I fix this issue? Please help me..

Comment: Have you tried using this certificate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21114601/846892?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, tried and worked..thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP cURL error code 60](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114371/php-curl-error-code-60)