# Wampserver 3.0 apache 2.4.17 cannot start

Tags: curl, openssl, wampserver, apache2.4, php-5.6

I configured `curl` with SSL certificate in `php.ini` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114371/php-curl-error-code-60) but still I got the error `cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`.

I thought the error may have occured due to `mod_openssl` module of apache server, and I tried to enable `mod_openssl` on Apache server 2.4.17, wampserver 3.0 but when I did wampserver could not start. After I disabled `mod_openssl` back, started fine.

What is the problem? How do I fix the curl SSL certificate error?

I am using:
wampserver 3.0
apache server 2.4.17
php 5.6.16

Comment: When you amended the `php.ini` which one did you amend, there are 2. To edit the one used by Apache use the wampmanager menus like so `wampmanager->PHP->php.ini`

Comment: I edited wamp->bin->php->php5.6.16->php.ini

Comment: That is the wrong ini file if you are cURLing from a web page. Use the menus as suggested above

Comment: It worked. Thanks so much. @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to activate `php_openssl.dll` this can be done by the menus as well.

```
wampmanager->PHP->PHP Extensions->php_openssl
```

make sure the `php_openssl` menu item has a tick beside it, if not click on it and it will amend the `php.ini` and restart Apache for you.

As Apache is not starting you may have to do this manually, in which case edit the `php.ini` using using the menus again

```
wampmanager->PHP->php.ini
```

Find this line

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

and remove the `;` comment marker. Then save, and restart Apache.

Comment: I enabled it already. Still not working. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: I would start by removing the ca-cert stuff, then see if cURL will work as you want now that `php_openssl` is activated.