# Mailgun Laravel 5.2 error 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

I encounter a problem when my application send the mail to reset a user's password in Laravel 5.2 with Mailgun but all the configuration lead me to nothing..

I configure my route like this :

```
Route::controllers([
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

[When I try this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etjbs.png)

[I get this error :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxKEg.png)

If anyone could help me it would be really cool.. thanks !

Comment: Try to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114371/php-curl-error-code-60

Comment: I don't see the link with my problem..