# Restful call in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, restful-url

I am very new to PHP. I wanted to call restful api in PHP. I am doing same in jQuery as below

```
var url;
url = "https://www.example.com/_api/lists/getbytitle('Stations')/items?$select=CityCode,CityNameEN&$filter=Active eq 'Yes'&$orderby=CityNameEN";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.d.results, function (i, item) {

                });
            }
        });
```

How can I do same in PHP. I have two difficulties. First in URL there is $ sign which PHP assume as variable and other I don't know how to do that

Comment: using php urlencoded method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send curl request with http header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264643/send-curl-request-with-http-header)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using curl for sending HTTP request.

```
<?php
$url='https://www.kuwaitairways.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'Stations\')/items?$select=OfficeId&$filter=CityCode%20eq%20%27KWI%27';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but there is small issue $select and $filter in URL php think as variable. How can we overcome that

Comment: @Milind I have udpated my post you can check it now. I have changed URL  variable in (`'`) single quotes. which will take it as a string rather than a variable

Comment: It did not work as URL itself has single quote for Stations

Comment: @Milind Oops i forgot to escape single quotes.. I have updated my post now check

Comment: @Milind can you provide me the exact url you want to hit

Comment: This is exact URL https://www.kuwaitairways.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Stations')/items?$select=OfficeId&$filter=CityCode eq 'KWI''

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138503/discussion-between-milind-and-sahil-gulati).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

```
$url="https://www.kuwaitairways.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Stations')/items?";
$url .= "\$select=OfficeId&\$filter=".urlencode("CityCode eq 'KWI'");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Check below code for fetching `d:OfficeId` node value

```
$office_id = "";
$xml=new DOMDocument;
$xml->loadXML($result);
$content_node = $xml->getElementsByTagName('content')->item(0);
foreach ($content_node->childNodes as $properties_node) {
    foreach ($properties_node->childNodes as $office_node) {
        $office_id = $office_node->nodeValue;
    }   
}
```

Comment: upvote for urlencode which help me to make clean dynamic URL

Comment: I am just trying search that output XML. How can I do that ?

Comment: You can use php xml parser functions provided inbuilt.
check this example https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_simplexml_read_string

Comment: There is no simple way to search particular tag value in PHP

Comment: you want to get d:OfficeId value? in that case what if you get multiple or is it fixed for one only?

Comment: Fixed for one only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138519/discussion-between-vara-prasad-and-milind).

Comment: I have solved the issue echo explode("</d:OfficeId>",explode("<d:OfficeId>", $string)[1])[0];