# cURL error 60 even after setting curl.cainfo in php.ini

Tags: php, curl

All the googling that I've done leads to either running `yum install ca-certificates -y` (it's already installed, so it changes nothing) or uncommenting a line in my php.ini and manually setting the location of the [latest certificate bundle](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html.). (I checked that the path was correct and I `chmod 777`'d the file but it still didn't work, so it couldn't be a location or permission problem) I've already done both, but I still get error 60. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114371/php-curl-error-code-60

Comment: I already did that on all the php.ini's on my system.